# how to create input like answer

Tags: c, string, rounding

I just need to create input so that users only have 2 options , `ceil` or `floor`.

If users select `ceil`, then show `void ceil`

If users select `floor`, then show `void floor`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


void testaval()
{
float ali1, ali2, ali3, ali4;

ali1 = 1.6;
ali2 = 1.2;
ali3 = -2.8;
ali4 = -2.3;

printf("val 1 = %.11f\n", floor(ali1));
printf("val 2 = %.11f\n", floor(ali2));
printf("val 3 = %.11f\n", floor(ali3));
printf("val 4 = %.11f\n", floor(ali4));

}

void testdovom()
{
float ali5, ali6, ali7, ali8;

ali5 = 1.6;
ali6 = 1.2;
ali7 = -2.8;
ali8 = -2.3;

printf("val 1 = %.11f\n", ceil(ali5));
printf("val 2 = %.11f\n", ceil(ali6));
printf("val 3 = %.11f\n", ceil(ali7));
printf("val 4 = %.11f\n", ceil(ali8));

}

int main()
{
char ce[] = {"ceil"};
char fl[] = {"floor"};
printf("hello choose one ceil or floor : 
\n" );
scanf("%s", &ceil);
scanf("%s", &floor);


if ( ce )

testdovom();

else ( fl );


testaval();

return 0;
}
```

Compilation succeeded in 0.33 seconds but when I run  it and type `ceil` or `floor` 
the program crashes.

Comment: What is `if (ce)` supposed do to? `else ( fl );` is total nonsense. Please [edit]  your question and show an example of input and expected output. BTW your program does not compile and your usage of `scanf` is more than questionable.

Comment: This doesn't compile with Clang or GCC in C++ and spits out [some warnings](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cwv0eZ) in C with popular warning options.

Comment: C or C++? The answer for one language may not be valid (or "good") for the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some fundamental coding errors needs to be addressed here along with logical flaw.

before we proceed lets format to 4 spaces

```
int main()
{
    /* Lets simplify these two statements */
    // char ce[] = {"ceil"};
    // char fl[] = {"floor"};

    char *ce = "ceil";
    char *fl = "floor";

    /* format this into one line .. */
    printf("hello choose one ceil or floor : \n" );
    /* instead of accepting two values, you may want to accept one 
       as per the question asked above the input is either floor or ceil */

    /* lets declare a buffer to store the choice */
    char choice[255];

    /* scan choice */   
    scanf("%s", choice );

    /* Below wont work, ceil and floor are already char * 
       &ceil and &floor will make them char ** so this wont work */ 
    // scanf("%s", &ceil);
    // scanf("%s", &floor);


    /* some commentary on this code snippet below */

    /* 1. ce is an address, a positive integer hence the if statement 
          will always evaluates to true
       2. else has an expression else() that is wrong syntax .
       3. else ending with ; another wrong syntax.

       lets say the below snippet wont compile 

    if ( ce ) 

        testdovom();

    else ( fl );


        testaval();

    */

    /* instead we use strcmp function from string.h 
       and  check if choice is "floor" or "ceil" */

   if( strcmp(choice, ce) == 0 )
   {
        testdovom();
   }
   else if( strcmp(choice, fl) == 0 )
   {
         testaval();
   }
   else
   {
        /* we've got something we donot handle */
        printf("Invalid input");
   }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not an answer. Reformatting the code doesn't fix the logic.

Comment: thanks for helping me sorry for bad sayin it but i have some errors buf was not declared in this scope , choice was not declared in this scope and strcmp was not declared in this scope

Comment: I've edited the code for choice, include <string.h> for strcmp

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write the input to the address of a function, that's just bound to crash. You need to read in a string like this:

```
char buf[256];
scanf("%s", buf);
```

And then you test if the string is what you wanted using `strcmp`:

```
if (!strcmp(buf, "ceil")) {
    testdovom();
}
else if (!strcmp(buf, "ceil")) {
    testaval();
}
else {
    printf("Invalid input.\n");
}
```